# AJAX save options inside class

Tags: ajax, oop, options, customization

I am creating a theme options page but with object oriented approach. Every new instance of this object is a separate subpage. Rendering and all the options work fine (still in progress, but in a nutshell it works fine), except the AJAX save.

I have placed in my `__construct` method this

```
public function __construct( $subpage_name, $html_array ) {
    $this->subpage_name = $subpage_name;
    $this->html_array   = $html_array;
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'create_submenu_pages' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_settings_save', array( $this, 'all_settings_save' ) );
}
```

And I have a method

```
public function all_settings_save() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['data'], $_POST['settings_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['settings_nonce'] ), 'settings_nonce_action' ) && '' !== $_POST['data'] ) { // Input var okay.
        $settings = json_decode( sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['data'] ) ) ); // Input var okay.
        update_option( str_replace( ' ', '_', strtolower( $this->subpage_name ) ), $settings );
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

When I click on the save button, my ajax works because I can see the data in the inspector (Network tab and then admin-ajax.php), for instance it shows that the form data is:

```
action:settings_save
data:{
  "settings": {
    "header_title": "Testing",
    "logo": "",
    "retina_logo": "",
    "retina_logo_width": "23",
    "retina_logo_height": "",
    "transparent_logo": "",
    "transparent_retina_logo": "",
    "transparent_retina_logo_width": "",
    "transparent_retina_logo_height": "",
    "background_image": ""
  }
}
settings_nonce:b7778588e3
```

So this should be stored in my database under, if it's 'Header Settings' page then it's `header_settings` option in my `wp_options` table. but when I reload the page nothing is inserted, because I have no row called `header_settings` present in the `wp_options` table.

I thought that the validation checks are failing, so I've removed them, but I still don't get a thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Enable debug log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG) (you also need `WP_DEBUG` set to `true`), run the code, check `wp-content/debug.log`, report back if you get anything

Comment: I have both `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` and `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` but I don't have debug.log or error.log. I need to check the settings of my server

Comment: I checked my error logs on server, and there is not a single error thrown :\

Comment: With the same settings in place, try some debug statements with `error_log( $message )` - maybe one at the start of the function `error_log( 'Running handler...' )`, one inside the `if`, and one just before `wp_die` - you'll then know if a) it's firing at all and b) if the code is running as you expected

Comment: Added it, and I get nothing. Is it possible that because my ajax action is being called in the `__construct()` method? Should I define a separate method and call it in the construct or something like that?

Comment: Ok, I added `ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);˙ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');` and got the error log to show. Upon running the ajax with the error messages, I get them in the log - both when I access the callback function and when I pass the validation, so now I just need to figure out why the `update_option` fails. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. First I added

```
ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
```

along the

```
define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE);
```

in my `wp-config.php`, this writes the errors, notices and warnings in the `error_log.txt` in the root folder (I don't know why I haven't thought of that in the first place).

Then I saw the errors - I used `json_decode` instead of `wp_json_encode` to encode my settings as a string before storing it in my option.

There is this weird issue of name being not of the subpage, but I'll get to that now.

Thanks to TheDeadMedic for suggesting the `error_message()` method of finding out if the code works or not. This will help with any AJAX debugging in the future.